# Is there a way to create a script with subscripts, using the same parameters as the parent-script and additional parameters of the subscript?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I'm trying to write a script, that has some default parameters and some subscripts. The parameters of the parent-script need to be used in combination with the parameters of the subscript in a pattern like the following:

```bash
./parentscript subscript -vned
```

Here's the parent-script:

`nms.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TEMP=$(getopt -o v --long verbose -n 'nms' -- "$@")
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
  echo "Aborting..." >&2
  exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$TEMP"

if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
  if [[ "$1" =~ ^-.+ ]]; then
    while true; do
      case "$1" in
      -v | --verbose)
        echo "debuglevel 4"
        ;;
      --)
        shift
        break
        ;;
      *)
        echo "$1 is not a valid parameter."
        break
        ;;
      esac
      shift
    done
  else
    method="$1"
    shift
    source ./$method
    $method "$@"
  fi
fi
```

Now in the subscript:

`system.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TEMP=$(getopt -o u --long update -n 'nms' -- "$@")
if [ "$?" != 0 ]; then
    echo "Aborting..." >&2
    exit 1
fi

eval set -- "$TEMP"

while true; do
  case "$1" in
  -u | --update)
    echo "system update"
    exit 0
    ;;
  --)
    shift
    break
    ;;
  *)
    echo "$1 is not a valid parameter."
    ;;
  esac
done
```

My goal is to achieve a script-call like this:

```bash
./nms system -vu
```

- `-v` - verbose (nms.sh)
- `-u` - update (system.sh)

The script first checks, if there are being parameters passed and after if the first parameter starts with a `-` e.g. `-v` or `--verbose`. If so, enter the while loop. If not, filter the subscript from the first parameter and pass the remaining parameters to the subscript.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected.
The script fails, since the `getopt` doesn't now the `-u` parameter and then exits after.
When removing the `$? != 0` check with the `exit 1` inside it prints:

```bash
nms: invalid option -- 'u'
-v -- system.sh
```

When removing `eval set -- "$TEMP"` and `$? != 0`, it prints:

```bash
nms: invalid option -- 'u'
system.sh -vu
nms: invalid option -- 'v'
Aborting...
```

In the last step, it clearly can be observed, that the `system.sh` script is getting sourced, since the `-v` option is invalid in the `system.sh`

The procedure needs to be scalable to more subscripts such as `user`, `package`, etc.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried my best to do so, while having the guide opened on my second screen. Would a GitLab Link laso satisfy this need?

Comment: It's hard to see what part of this is minimal; there's a lot of logic that might be a legit part of the thing you're trying to build, but isn't strictly required to showcase your technical problem. (If you only need one of `-n` or `-v`, take the other out; there should only be the **shortest possible** code that produces your issue when run without changes, with everything inessential removed)

Comment: Okay, I tried to achieve it like you told. Now with the "original" script, but stripped to the bare minimum. Both code-parts can be copied and executed in their individual file. 

There are a few steps to remove some code-bits to achieve a different output.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to separate flags between parent and subscript, rather than put all flags together at the end of command, e.g.

```
./nms -vn system -u
```

Following is my solution `nms.sh`, where `-s` is for subscript and `-p` for subscript parameters.

```
echo "Execute parent script $0"
while getopts ":s:p:hVvn" OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
    V) echo "Received parentscript flag -V: version";;
    v) echo "Received parentscript flag -v: debugLevel";;
    n) echo "Received parentscript flag -n: dryrun";;
    s) subscript="$OPTARG";;
    p) subflags="$OPTARG";;
    h|?) echo "Show help message";;
    esac
done

# Execute subscript
if [ -f ./sub/$subscript ]; then
    ./sub/$subscript $subflags
fi
```

And the `system.sh`

```
echo "Execute subscript $0"
while getopts ":hcu" OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
    c) echo "Received subscript flag -c: highstateCall";;
    u) echo "Received subscript flag -u: update";;
    h|?) echo "Show help message";;
    esac
done
```

Here is the command and the result

```
$ ./nms -vn -s system -p -uc
Execute parent script ./nms
Received parentscript flag -v: debugLevel
Received parentscript flag -n: dryrun
Execute subscript ./sub/system
Received subscript flag -u: update
Received subscript flag -c: highstateCall
```

Comment: Thank you. Isn't there another way to do so? Needing the subscript to be called via a parameter isn't quite the solution I had in mind.